# Accessing XAML Text Box in Another Name Space

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I started the project with two different namespaces, which probably is not good practice but its nearly done.

I have a textbox

```
 <TextBox x:Name="txtStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="55,272,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="241" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

In namespace one, that I want to access in anotherClass in NameSpace2.

Is it possible to make this reference?

Comment: There's no "accessing" anything. Use proper DataBinding. Start reading [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Agreeing with @HighCore, if you need to access a UI control from a class that doesn't own it, then you are probably doing something wrong. If you absolutely *must* access it, then you need a public property in the class that owns it that will expose the control.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the textbox to a property on a class instance using the mode `TwoWay`. Then allow the other instance a reference to the the instance which has the property and change the property as needed; results shown on the screen regardless of who/what changes it.